# How to represent dynamically derived data? (model without a table?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tables for **salespeople**, **products**, and **sales_activities** (consider these to be 'transactions', but Rails reserves that name, so I'm calling them sales_activities).

For each salesperson, I need to dynamically derive their sales_total for a given day.

To do this, I run through the list of **sales_activities**, and create my derived content list (as an array of objects that hold salesperson_id & sales_total). I then want to display it in a view somewhat equivalent to an 'index' view of **salespeople**, but this view does not correspond to any of the existing index views I already have, due to the extra field (sales_total).

My question is how do I best define the class (or whatever) for each instance of my dynamically derived data (salesperson_id + sales_total)? It seems I could use a model without a table (with columns salesperson_id and the derived sales_total).  That way, I could build an array of instances of these types as I generate the dynamic content, and then hand off the resulting array to the corresponding index view. However, from reading around, this doesn't seem 'the Rails way'.

I'd really appreciate advice on how to tackle this.  The examples I've seen only show cases where a single overall total is required in the index view, and not dynamic content per row that can't be derived by a simple 'sum' or equivalent.

[This is a simplified explanation of the actual problem I'm trying to solve, so I'd appreciate help with the 'dynamically derived view / model without table' problem, rather than a short-cut answer to the simplified problem outlined above, thanks]

Comment: Ignoring your last remark, are you sure you need this model without table? From what you've written here, it seems to make much more sense to have `def sales_total` in your `Salesperson` model. In that method you would just calculate the sales total for that sales person.

Comment: Thanks, but what [I think] I'm really looking for are hints as to how to be able to declare a type/class for these dynamically derived objects.

Comment: Well from what you are writing here, you only need a hash or an array to store two values that are related to each other. Then in your view you can just iterate over them. What I am trying to say is that each sales person has a sales total. This is a strong hint that it should be an attribute of `SalesPerson`.

Comment: My real case is more complicated, but I've tried (and quite possibly failed ;-) to capture the complexity in my question.  I believe I can't have a sales_total per SalesPerson as it's calculated per day, and is dynamically derived from the SalesActivity transactions.  I do appreciate your comments.

Comment: Sorry, to be a pain in the ass, but the reasons you mention for not having `sales_total` as an attribute of `Salesperson` don't convince me. The fact that it's calculated per day can be easily solved by doing `sales_total(date = Date.today)` and I assume a `Salesperson has_many :sales_activities`, so you should have access to all the transactions for a particular sales person. But, if you are convinced this is not possible I will not bother you anymore.

Comment: You are certainly not being a pain, thanks for your patience. I think I may have confused your suggestion of a 'def sales_total' method, with it being a SalesPerson 'table/column' attribute. I'll need to think on this some more. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean table column. I mean that you do the calculation in that method. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a plain Ruby class would do the trick?

```
class SalesStats
  def initialize(sales_person, date_range = Date.today)
    @sales_person = sales_person
    @date_range = date_range
  end

  def results
    # return a array or hash (anything which responds to an 'each' method), e.g:
    SalesActivity.find(:all, :conditions => { :sales_person => @sales_person, :created_at => @date_range }).group_by(&:sales_person).collect { |person, sales_activities| { :person => person, :total => sales_activities.sum(&:price) } }        
  end
end
```

in the view:

```
<% @sales_stats.results.each do | stat | %>
 <%= stat[:person] %> - <%= stat[:total] %>
<% end %>
```

However like mischa said in the comments this could equally be achieved using a method on SalePerson:

```
class SalesPerson < AR::Base
  has_many :sales_activities

  def total_sales(date_range)
    sales_activities.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => date_range }).collect { ... }
  end
end
```

Note: date_range can be a single date or a range e.g (Date.today-7.days)..Date.today

Comment: Thanks Kris, and Mischa before.  With your help, I've realised I don't need a model without a table, and can go with the solutions you suggest.  I appreciate your help.